# the string variable acting strangely

Tags: c++

I tried making a little program that checks if a string is a substring of another. I think got the logic down correctly, but i encountered a problem concerning **data types.** I declared 2 strings and gave them a value instantly and they worked fine, but the other one, the `checker` variable, works in a weird way. It can not be printed out like a regular string using `cout` but it only prints the first letter. And functions like `.length()` do not work on it, the error says

`|error: request for member 'length' in 'checker', which is of non-class type 'std::__cxx11::string`

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text = "abcde";
    string subtext = "bcde";
    //string specialChars = "\\*";
    string checker[subtext.length()];
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if (subtext[counter] == text[i]){
            checker[counter] = text[i];
            counter++;
        }

    }
    cout << text << " " << checker.length() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        cout << checker[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Bonus question ^_^: Is the logic behind the program good enough, or is there a more efficient way of solving it.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Tip: `using namespace std;` is a bad habit to get into and if you can stop now you might avoid a whole lot of headaches in the future. The `std::` prefix is there for a reason: It avoids conflict with your own classes, structures and variables especially when you’re importing a lot of header files which may define a lot more things than they superficially appear to.

Comment: Note that [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not part of standard C++. Please try to avoid it in favor of `std::vector` (which will as noted in an answer also solve your problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string checker[subtext.length()];
```

is an array of `subtext.length()` empty `std::string`s. Not what you want to have if you indeed want a string of the shared character. Which you don't. More on that after the post-mortem.

```
string checker(subtext.length(), ' ');
```

Will give you a single `std::string` of the requested length using  spaces as place-holder characters. This is also the wrong thing to do because now you have to deal with left-over unused spaces still containing spaces.

What you need in order to correct the code you currently have is a single empty `std::string`  and a change to the loop that builds it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string text = "abcde";
    std::string subtext = "bcde";
    std::string checker;

    int counter = 0;

    for(std::string::size_type i = 0; // unlikely to happen, but int may not be
                                      // big enough. size_type is guaranteed
        i < text.length(); // avoid magic numbers. Use the length of the string
        i++){
        if (subtext[counter] == text[i]){
            checker.push_back(text[i]); //add to checker
            counter++;
        }

    }
    std::cout << text << " " << checker.length() << std::endl
              << checker << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

That's it for the post-mortem. The code works as I believe the asker intends. Unfortunately it doesn't detect [substrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring). For a string to be a substring not only do all of the letters have to match and be in the same order, they also need to be contiguous. The way it is built, `checker` can't guarantee this.

The easiest way to find a substring is

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string text = "abcde";
    std::string subtext = "bcde";

    if (text.find(subtext) != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::cout << "We Got One!";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[`find` looks for the exact `subtext` inside `text`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and returns the location of `subtext` inside `text`. If `subtext` is not found, `find` returns an impossible index, `npos`.

If you have to search the hard way, as in the assignment won't all of you to call a library function to do the dirty work, [there are many approaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm) with Knuth-Morris-Pratt being relatively easy to implement, pretty darn efficient, and [extremely well documented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

`checker` is not a `std::string`, it's an array of `std::string`, and as a primitive type, does not have a `.length()` function.<sup>1</sup>

If you want that, you'll need to use this instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> checker;
```

Where then you can add as many as you see fit:

```
checker.push_back(text[i]);
```

And later:

```
cout << text << " " << checker.size() << endl;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Not everything in the C++ Standard Library has a `length()` function anyway, it's conventionally called `size()`. `std::string` just has an alias, but it's an exception.

Comment: My suspicion is the asker really wants `string checker(' ', subtext.length());` and this is just a typo (and errors descending from the typo while trying to make the code compile).

Comment: @user4581301 A very good point. Worth adding as a separate answer?

Comment: I was commenting and about to close as typo when I saw your answer pop up and decided to stop and wait for more input.

Comment: The expression `string checker[subtext.length()];` is not valid C++, as VLA are supported in C99 and sometimes as an extension in C++. Visual Studio doesn't compile it.

Comment: I know std stands for standard library, but what is std::vector. And what are the <> signs used for in this context. I am willing to read abt it so i fully understand it.

Comment: If you're learning C++ and don't know that yet, time to get a reference which covers [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates). They're extremely important to know, and if you don't, then 90% of the Standard Library will be off-limits and useless, which is a huge impediment. A template is a C++ "generic" of sorts. C++ is not something you can intuit your way through, so a good reference book is absolutely critical to understanding it.

Comment: I dropped a bug above. `string checker(' ', subtext.length());` should be `string checker(subtext.length(), ' ');`

Comment: So, if i'm not mistaken, the string class takes 2 arguments, size and content. But why did the first 2 string variables work fine and not the checker variable?

Comment: In C++ `X y[n]` creates a C array of type `X` with `n` entries. That `[n]` part doesn't even hit the constructor, it means *create `n` of*. You want `X y(...)` where the `...` part *is* passed to the constructor.

Comment: So, I must dig into templates and the ::std prefix for the next few weeks i guess.

Comment: The `std::` prefix isn't the hard part, it just means "don't slap `using namespace std` on your code and instead embrace prefixing with `std::`" so that's easy. The harder part is understanding how templates work. Getting up to speed on something simple like `std::vector<X>` doesn't take long, that template is very forgiving, but writing your own templates can be challenging, so don't be discouraged.

Comment: What are some sources where i can learn about templates. Are youtube videos enough? If not, what is the best place to learn about them in your opinion?

Comment: YouTube videos might work for a "quick introduction" but they're no substitute for a solid reference. I found [*The C++ Programming Language*](https://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) to be very thorough, it's written by the originator of C++, and was essential for my understanding of C++. There's also a [large book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) here worth checking out.